# switch classes depending on value

Tags: c#

I have two classes which share the identical methods and I would like to switch them in code depending on requirement. If you will look at example below you will find that the same portion of code is duplicated. The CacheFile and CacheMemory classes are identical, I am sure this code can be shrinked and CacheFile and CacheMemory classes can be switched.

```
    if (_cacheLocation == CacheLocation.File)
    {
        if (!CacheFile.Get(key, out value))
        {
            // Do lookup based on caller's logic.   
            context.Proceed();
            value = context.ReturnValue;
            CacheFile.Add(value, key, _cacheType, _expiry);
        }
    }

    if (_cacheLocation == CacheLocation.Memory)
    {
        if (!CacheMemory.Get(key, out value))
        {
            // Do lookup based on caller's logic.   
            context.Proceed();
            value = context.ReturnValue;
            CacheMemory.Add(value, key, _cacheType, _expiry);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to use a common Interface to both, and call the "get"/"add" methods on the object (and not the class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make CacheLocation and Cache Memory implement a common interface, you can use the interface instead of the individual class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: I know about Interfaces but could you show example how to switch between classed which is implement interface?

Comment: Instead of assigning a value to the _cacheLocation field, use a field which stores the cache using the interface as its type. Then you can get rid of your if statements and call the methods on the interface instead. To switch the classes, assign the value of the property which holds the interface in the same location that you're currently assigning the _cacheLocation field, by instantiating the chosen class.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class that encapsulates the replicated behavior (define an interface that exposes this behavior). Implement this interface on two classes that perform the intended action for CacheLocation.File and CacheLocation.Memory.

You can then use a factory that returns an ICache, given a CacheLocation and consumers can use it without knowing what kind of actual store it uses underneath.

Comment: Can you show how to switch between classes? I know how to implement interface, not problem here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could handle this. If CacheMemory and CacheFile inherit from each other, or a common base class you can declare a variable of the parent class and work with that. Alternatively, if you don't want to derive one from the other (or both from a common base) you can have them both implement a common interface and use a variable declared as an instance of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface as below, inherit CacheFile and CacheMemory from it.

```
public interface ICache
{
   Get();
   Add();
}
```

It could reduce the code bloat.

Comment: How to switch between classes in my case?